# How do I fix this discord music bot error?

Tags: python, heroku, discord, bots, youtube-dl

I am a discord.py developer ,so I just added a music command in my bot that plays music when you give the play command with a YouTube video link . My bot does not play the full song , it stops after sometime and gives this error in the log (hosted on Heroku).

```
2021-09-06T07:18:13.751380+00:00 app[worker.1]: [tls @ 0x5eb4080] Error in the pull function.
2021-09-06T07:18:13.751391+00:00 app[worker.1]: [tls @ 0x5eb4080] IO error: Connection reset by peer
2021-09-06T07:18:13.751394+00:00 app[worker.1]: [tls @ 0x5eb4080] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
2021-09-06T07:18:13.751414+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Last message repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solutions to [this issue on the discord.py repo](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/315), it seems that you can solve it by first downloading the Youtube video first and then playing it.

```
import youtube_dl

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
ydl.download([url])
```

The downside is that it would take a few seconds before the song would start playing.